# Vector autoregressive model selection process and relationship with cointegration

Tags: time-series, econometrics, cointegration, vector-autoregression

Let's say you're looking at two securities that trade closely with one another and you suspect you can somehow trade the spread. How can you use VAR models to estimate the relationship between the two? I'd be interested in a step-by-step approach similar to the Box-Jenkins approach for selecting an ARIMA model.

For example, in the case of an ARIMA model:
1) perform an ADF to test for a unit root, 2) difference and retest the data if necessary, 3) plot the ACF/PACF, 4) select the appropriate coefficients based on the ACF/PACF structure and/or AIC/BIC and whatnot, 5) perform a Ljung-Box test on the residuals to test for white noise (I don't even know if I'm right about the whole thing, I'm still learning all this).

Could you please briefly describe a similar process for vector autoregressions in a relatively simple manner (do you need stationary data or not, how do you find the model coefficients, and how do you test the model after)? For implementation, would you recommend a specific software package? I've been using R lately, but have access to gretl or EViews as well.

Lastly, how are VAR models related to cointegration, if at all? [EDIT: I just read that "cointegration is to VAR models as unit roots are to stationary time series" somewhere. Should I then test for cointegration prior to running a VAR?]

Instead of a detailed answer, I wouldn't mind a link that clearly explains this from scratch. The issue is 90% of the content I read on econometrics seems to be aimed at graduate students and isn't very accessible to more junior students like myself.. I haven't been able to find anything helpful for VAR models so far.

Thank you very much! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Vector error correction model (VECM) would be more natural to model two securities with a stable spread. This is a kind of VAR model for cointegrated variables. An example of VECM applied for the so-called *pairs trading* can be found in Tsay "Analysis of Financial Time Series" textbook, 3rd edition (2010), section 8.8 page 446 and onwards.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I've hit a hurdle. It appears that both your time series need to be I(1) for you to even proceed with VECM. Given that stock returns do not exhibit statistically significant autocorrelation, both my time series are I(0). Does that mean I can't apply VECM?

Comment: Update: Never mind, my question didn't make sense. I simply used actual prices and adjusted the time frame (one series wasn't I(1) over a 20-year sample for some reason).

Comment: Yes, just use the stock price series instead of return series in the VECM. (If one price series does not seem to be I(1) based on statistical tests, maybe it is just a coincidence; perhaps you could use an argument that the stock price is likely I(1) nevertheless. But that depends on whether you trust the theory more than the data.)